# can not create a database with PHP and my syntax is correct

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

How is it is can not create a database on phpMyAdmin? I connect to PHP just fine, no error message. But when I am trying to create a database so phpMyAdmin, I keep getting error. In case it matters I have one page with a `<form>` and has a submit to my `second.php` file where my database code is (`second.php` is shown below).

I am pretty much trying to display the database in phpMyAdmin but nothing shows up:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
            if(!$con){
                echo "could not connect";
            } else {
                echo "good connection";
            }

            //creation of database
            $sql= 'CREATE DATABASE project';
            if(mysql_query($sql,$con)){
                echo 'DB created succesfully';
            } else {
                echo 'error creating DB' . mysql_errno();
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure the user you are attempting to create the table with has been granted the 'CREATE' privilege.

Comment: Also, what is the error number you have been given from `mysql_errno()`?

Comment: What `mysql_errno()` tells you?

Comment: You connected with `mysqlI` and are using `mysql` the rest of the time.  Pick 1 library and use only that.

Comment: Make sure the user willc86 have privilege to create DATABASEs and not only tables within a selected DATABASE, [make sure you start and end your code using the same PHP MySQL library unlike what you're doing right now.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-create-db.php)

Comment: You're not making any database on phpMyAdmin. You're trying to create a database on a MySQL server... phpMyAdmin is simply a client program (one of many such programs) that allows you to access databases on a MySQL server

Comment: Putting Diesel fun in a Ferrari

Comment: what do you guys mean about not making a database on myphpadmin? so I need to download MySQL?

Comment: "I keep getting error..." - what is the error?

Answer (score 1):

One issue is you connected with mysql`i` and are using mysql the rest of the time. Pick 1 (not mysql) library and use only that.

```
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
```

and

```
echo 'error creating DB' . mysqli_error($con);
```

Comment: `Pick 1` = `mysqli_*` ;-)

Comment: or **PDO** :) which IMHO is way better and gives you more alternatives.