# phpmyADMIN or mySQL? I am a bit confused with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hey guys the code below is what I am trying to run. I am trying to run a practice MySQL server because I am going to host it on my schools free database which is MySQL

I am using phpmyADMIN but I am a bit confused because yall are saying I am not connecting to MySQL

so what is this code to create a database? Do I need to download MySQL or something? I thought phpmyadmin is the same syntax to create a database/tables/ and values? since I have MySQL turned on?

```
    //creation of database
    $sql= 'CREATE DATABASE project';
    if(mysql_query($sql,$con)){
        echo 'DB created succesfully';
    }
    else{
        echo 'error creating DB' . mysql_errno();
    }
```

Comment: You have to first connect to MySQL. MySQL is the server software that talks with and manages the database. The database is configured and accessed by MySQL. PhpMyAdmin is in turn a way for you to talk to MySQL to manipulate the database. It's written in PHP. You need some more research to fully understand what you're saying.

Comment: *"I am a bit confused because yall are saying I am not connecting to MySQL"* - sounds like you've already asked a related question elsewhere.  If you have further questions about it, update your original question instead of posting multiples on the same topic.

Comment: MySQL is a Database. PHPMyAdmin is *only* a Database-Administration-Tool.

Comment: The context is this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740764/can-not-create-a-database-with-php-and-my-syntax-is-correct which was about running CREATE DATABASE from a PHP script (not phpMyAdmin)

Answer (score 1):

PHPMyAdmin is a web-based software program created with PHP to help you administrate MySQL databases.  It has its own internally built code to connect to your MySQL databases and perform standard functions such as insert, select, delete, update, etc.

PHPMyAdmin does not really have anything to do with you creating your own PHP program.  You will still need to connect to MySQL (as PHPMyAdmin does behind the scenes).  You can still use the same code that PHPMyAdmin generates for you for use in your own PHP programs, but you must already be connected to MySQL as a user with valid permissions.

In your PHP code it is important to note that you are using the mysql_* functions which have been deprecated and you should be using the mysqli_* functions instead.

Your code should actually look something like this:

```
//connect to db
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password");
//creation of database
$sql= 'CREATE DATABASE project';
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo 'DB created succesfully';
}
else{
    echo 'error creating DB' . mysqli_errno();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is the database server you connect to in order to execute queries such as `CREATE DATABASE project`. phpmyadmin is a PHP-based front end to MySQL to allow easier browsing and manipulation of the database.

Think of text documents on your computer. `notes.txt` is a text file, but you could open it with any text editor such as Notepad or TextEdit.

Your specific snippet of code is missing the database connection string, so something more appropriate might look like:

```
$connection = new mysqli('db_host', 'db_user', 'db_pass');
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE project";
$results = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
//check for errors
```

Without connecting to the database, your SQL is all just strings of text with no meaning.

Comment: so why wont $sql = "CREATE DATABASE my_db1"; wont work in php using php myadmin? how do I make it work?

Comment: are you actually using phpmyadmin or are you trying to execute a php script?

Comment: If you are logged into phpmyadmin, then the only code you can execute is just SQL statements.  Like: create database my_db1

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP referencing this and the other q he asked on SO, doesn't look like he is using phpmyadmin at all...just a heads up

Answer (score -1):

I tried a lot hoping to get a good job here
If you are logged into phpmyadmin, then the only code you can execute is just SQL statements. Like: create database my_db1

Comment: This doesn't really help OP or improve on the existing answers. Please do not provide answer to old posts unless you have something meaningful to add to the conversation.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33178395)